# requestAnimationFrame loops with timestamps in PureScript

Tags: functional-programming, requestanimationframe, purescript

I am trying to pick up PureScript. Something I do a lot in JS is the following:

```js
let start;
function step(timestamp) {
  if (start === undefined)
    start = timestamp;

  const elapsed = timestamp - start;
    
  console.log(elapsed);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

I've managed to get a loop going like this:

```purescript
main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  w <- window
  step w

step :: Window -> Effect Unit
step w = do
  log "timestamp?!"
  requestAnimationFrame (step w) w $> unit
```

However, I don't know where to go from here, I'm not even sure how I could get `step` to take a timestamp parameter with `requestAnimationFrame`'s signature in PureScript:
`Effect Unit -> Window -> Effect RequestAnimationFrameId`

Answer (score 0):

The library has `requestAnimationFrame` defined without a parameter for some reason, so no luck there (consider submitting a pull request to the library).

If I know more details about the ultimate purpose of doing that, I might recommend a better approach. Chances are, in PureScript you don't have to use `requestAnimationFrame` at all. PureScript has `Aff` for example, that might be better suited.

But without knowing the specifics, if I had to translate that JS code to PureScript as closely as possible, I would recommend defining your own FFI binding for `requestAnimationFrame`.

In your foreign module, `MyModule.js`:

```js
export function requestAnimationFrame(f) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(ts => f(ts)())
}
```

In your PureScript module, `MyModule.purs`:

```hs
foreign import requestAnimationFrame :: (Int -> Effect Unit) -> Effect Unit
```

And that's it. Now you can call your own version of `requestAnimationFrame` and pass it a function that takes a parameter:

```
step :: Window -> Int -> Effect Unit
step w ts = do
  log (show ts)
  requestAnimationFrame (step w)
```

Comment: Thanks for the FFI example. I need to use rAF's timestamp because we have a lot of animations that interpolate dependent on the time elapsed since it was kicked off.